# Data Overlapping in google spreadsheet using query referencing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know this question may be kind of stupid, but I face difficulties when using QUERY and IMPORTRANGE formulas to build a merged table.

The case is something like this, the first table I use IMPORTRANGE to import data from another spreadsheet, while the second table I use QUERY to build a copy of Google Form Responses. Both of them having the same column header.

When I try to use `=QUERY({zenRecord!G1:K;'payment record'!A2:E})`

Only one of the table's record will be display.

I have also tried `={QUERY(zenRecord!G1:K);QUERY('payment record'!A2:E)}`

However, the result turns out to be the same.

Though it seems fixed by setting the range G1:K to G1:K10 and A2:E5 (which is the **current size of the query in each corresponding table**), but I want to make it auto determines the ending point as I don't know how many records will be input.

Do anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your sheet, but I suspect this does work:

```
=QUERY({zenRecord!G1:K;'payment record'!A2:E})
```

but the results from `'payment record'!A2:E` are displayed far down the page after all of the blank cells in `zenRecord!G1:K`.

Try:

```
=QUERY({zenRecord!G1:K;'payment record'!A2:E},"where Col1 is not null",1)
```

- change `Col1` for whatever col has data in all rows.